# Testing a MacBook Pro's RAM upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, memory, apple-hardware-test

What are the best possible RAM tests that can be run on a MacBook Pro (Early 2011 running Mountain Lion) after upgrading RAM from 4 GB to 16 GB?

I see there a quite a few tools out there and the Apple CD hardware test itself.

I figured I'd ask here hoping to get a much more educated, experienced and consolidated answer.

Answer (score 6):

As someone who has to test RAM every day (Apple Certified Macintosh Technician for 2.5 years), I've found that the best RAM testing utility hands down is [Memtest](http://osxdaily.com/2011/05/03/memtest-mac-ram-test/).

It's really easy to use too!  First, copy it to `/usr/bin` then [boot to single-user mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1492).  Next, type in `mount -uw /` to mount your internal drive (for logging purposes) and finally type in `memtest all -L 3` to start the Memtest suite.

If you want to perform more loops, change the 3 to a number you desire (e.g. `memtest all -L 5`), I reckon 3 to 5 loops is the best because it gives the RAM time to heat up (intermittent RAM failures can be heat related).

**edit**: Just wanted to add that Apple Hardware Test is useless, so never use it for testing hardware, *especially* RAM.

Comment: The link goes to a site that's down. Via http://osxdaily.com/2011/05/03/memtest-mac-ram-test/ I found this direct link: http://cdn.command-tab.com/2008/memtest_422.zip . "Apple Hardware Test is useless": What specifically is useless about it?