# ram upgrade works in safe mode but not in normal mode

Tags: imac, upgrade, memory

I have new installed 8 gb ram in to my 2010 imac i3.

It kernel panic when booted, but worked when I start it in safe mode.

It also shows as 12 GB ram. ( 4 Gb original and 8 gb new. )

How can I make it work in normal mode ?

Comment: did you verify that you bought the right RAM for your machine? (just do a search for "what RAM for my mac")

Comment: I did, what i wonder is it is working in safe mode, but not in normal mode.

Comment: yea, as long as you know it's the right kind it's highly likely it's just a bad RAM stick. let them know and they'll swap it out pretty quickly for you I'd bet.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to simply remove and reseat the chips. Restart, zapping the P-RAM as you go - might be surprised to find it's all okay.

Answer (score 0):

Safe mode does not utilize the full 12 gig.

I would do the RAM test to make sure it is working.

[Here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59916/testing-a-macbook-pros-ram-upgrade) is a link to a very good way to do that.

> Download MemTest for Mac for Free
>
> Memtest is from the broader UNIX world and it that has been ported to
>   Mac OS X.  For whatever reason, there are some websites who are
>   charging for the free utility, but you should not need to pay for it
>   because it is free, open source, and there are Mac versions available
>   from developers as free downloads: